# How to change default sendmail SMTP error codes, responses, and/or DSN text?

Tags: linux, email, centos, smtp, sendmail

CentOS 5.x - SendMail

Hi Guys,

I'm curious -- is there any way to customize the STMP error codes, response text, and/or DSN body text in sendmail?

If so, where is this stored?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, but probably not worth it.

You can **go through the source code** (benefit of open source) and **modify the interesting parts** by hand (most if not all strings seem to be hardcoded).

Fast way to find the strings is to use some recursive `grep`.

It would **ruin your update path** though, so I doubt it's a viable solution really.

Comment: Cool. I was hoping for something like an m4 variable but didn't see any listed in the sendmail docs. Thanks for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time I wrote [$#random](http://blog.postmaster.gr/2007/10/23/random-a-local-mailer-that-returns-a-random-ex_/), a mailer that returns random exit codes. You maybe interested in modifying that to your purpose.

Comment: This is a clever idea!